# send messages to a computer off network python

Tags: python, sockets, messaging

I am writing a messaging software based off of the code at this link:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578802-send-messages-between-computers/

I love this code and it works well, but it will not let me send messages to computers that are not on my network.  I was wondering if there is a way that I could modify this code, so that I could send a message to a computer anywhere.

Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: If the computer is on the World Wide Web then to some extent it *is* on your network, it just likely doesn't have a public-facing IP address that you can talk to.

Comment: Chances are source and/or destination network are behind NAT. There are two ways to communicate in this case: either use a central server with a public address in order to relay messages between clients (like IRC does) or set port forward in every NAT firewall to allow communication. There are higher level libraries to deal with network communication, dealing with plain sockets is painful, check out tornado or twisted.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work.
Can you use ping to confirm the destination.
If you computer is on an internal network external machines may be only seeing your NAT address, that is an address that you internal network presents to the outside world. Also the computer you are trying to send to would need to have and external IP, that is not an address reserved for internal networks.
Ideally both computer you are wanting to chat with would have non internal IPs.

Comment: This answer is factually correct, but could be just a comment as well.

Comment: How do you get a non-internal IP address?

Comment: If it should work from anywhere than why does it say on the website that it will only work on your network?

Comment: Certain IP ranges are restricted to internal address. They are     addresses: 10.x.x.x   172.16.somethingIforget    192.168.x.x, An external address will neot begin with those numbers. You still need to look at you firewall.

Answer (score -1):

That code recipe uses datagram sockets (UDP protocol), often these are blocked by a gateway/proxy/firewall. You may have to switch to using TCP instead.

Comment: I don't think this matters. Most networks use many-to-one NAT (source NAT) and there is no way to connect both UDP and TCP from the public network unless you set up port forwarding in the firewall. The "blocking" is a natural side effect of source NAT.

Comment: Yeah, also I think I got confused with UDP multicast.  Usually regular UDP gets routed just fine I guess (besides NAT issues)